# How to do :hover on circle navigation from angle x to y

Tags: html, css

I've following HTML code:

```
    <div id="wrap2">
        <div id="shape2">
            <a href="#" id="moveTop"><i class="ion ion-arrow-up-b"></i></a>
            <a href="#" id="moveRight"><i class="ion ion-arrow-up-b"></i></a>
            <a href="#" id="moveDown"><i class="ion ion-arrow-up-b"></i></a>
            <a href="#" id="moveLeft"><i class="ion ion-arrow-up-b"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And following CSS code:

```
#shape2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
}

#shape2:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

#moveTop{
    position: fixed;
  top: 42px;
  left: 80px;
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

#moveRight{
  position: fixed;
  top: 110px;
  left: 148px;
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#moveDown{
  position: fixed;
  top: 178px;
  left: 80px;
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#moveLeft{
  position: fixed;
    top: 110px;
  left: 12px;
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

How to do properly navigation with arrows? I mean that If user have mouseover arrow to move top `#moveTop` it should change background of that "white" border within angel x to y to color #eee.

There's example of my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/L9aeu4o3/6/

Comment: Please include your `Javascript` code in the question.

Comment: @MelanciaUK JavaScript is used for drag'n drop. Not for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm right here, you want the arc behind the arrow to be highlighted?

To do that you need to place a div between your `<a>`tags, like so:

```
    <a href="#" id="moveTop">
<i class="ion ion-arrow-up-b"></i>
<div id="highlightTop"></div>
</a>
```

looks horrible doesn't it?

and in your CSS you are going to want to do the following:

```
#moveTop:hover #highlightTop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 41px;
    left: 41px;
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    border: 19px solid #eee;
    min-width: 4em;
    min-height: 4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

It's a fiddly solution, but there's no jquery, just a pure CSS/HTML solution.

Here's the [jsfiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/L9aeu4o3/10/)